# Microsoft Graph API - "Decline event" call fails

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-mail

We have an app that monitors resource mailboxes, and applies validation checks when one accepts a meeting invite from a user.  If these validation checks fail, the code makes the Graph API call to tell the mailbox to decline the invite.

We are encountering a scenario where the Graph call to decline the invite fails.  Specifically it's when the user sent the invite with "request responses" unchecked.  The Graph call fails with the message **Your request can't be completed. The meeting organizer hasn't requested a response.**

So basically the users have found a way to work around our validation system, by simply unchecking "request responses" when inviting these resource mailboxes to meetings.

Edited to clarify my question: Is there any way, via the API, to tell a resource mailbox to decline in invitation, if the organizer unchecked "request responses?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Is there any way, via the API, to tell a resource mailbox to decline in invitation, if the organizer unchecked "request responses?"